# Powershell 5 : Cannot convert value To System.String

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a PS script with which I read a csv file line by line into a variable :

CSV :

```
  header1;header2
  column1;column2
```

PS Script :

```
#-------------------------
#   Func declarations    
#-------------------------
function myFunc{
   param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$param1,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$param2
   )
   #Do something
}

#-------------------------
#       Run    
#-------------------------

$lines = Import-Csv .\etc\file.csv -Delimiter ";" -Header "header1","header2"

foreach($line in $lines) {
    myFunc -param1 $line.header1 -param2 $line.header1
}
```

The call
`myFunc -param1 $line.header1` throws a:

> Cannot convert value To
> System.String (...) ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException

Checking the type of $line.header1 (or $line.header2)  with `$line.header1.GetType()` returns as expected `System.string`.

- If I remove one parameter (whichever), it works
- If I remove the type
  definition on the first like so :
  `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$param1`, the first one is recognized
  but the second is null...

Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note: As of this writing, there's no explanation for the specific symptoms described in the question, and Sandy reports their problem as now resolved.
**This answer generally explains under what circumstance you'll see the
`Cannot convert value to type System.String` error when passing an argument to a `[string]`-typed parameter**.

---

With your sample function, which by virtue of using a `[Parameter()]` attribute is implicitly an [*advanced* function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced), there are only two ways that passing a value to your `[string]`-typed parameters can fail:

- passing `$null` or an *empty string* (such as `''` or `""`)<sup>[1]</sup>
- passing an *array*<sup>[2]</sup> instead of a single value.

If you pass a value of any other type, it is automatically converted to a string.

Given the error message you received, the latter must be the problem, as demonstrated here:

```bash
function myFunc { 
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] # NOTE: This makes the function an *advanced* function.
    [string] $param1
  )
  "[$param1]"
}

# FAILS, because an *array* can't be passed as a *single string*
# to an *advanced* function's [string] parameter.
myFunc -param1 'one', 'two'
```

This yields the following error (which, sadly, doesn't reveal the specific cause):

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'param1'. 
Cannot convert value to type System.String
```

**The inability to pass an *array* to a `[string]` parameter applies only to *advanced* functions** (the explicit alternative to making a function *implicitly* an advanced one via a `[Parameter()` attribute is to place a `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute above the `param(...)` block).

**A simple (non-advanced) function *does* accept an array as a `[string]` argument**, and simply joins the array elements with spaces<sup>[3]</sup> on conversion; e.g.,
`'one', 'two'` turns into `'one two'`

Note: Arguably, passing an array to a `[string]` parameter should *always* require a deliberate action on the caller's part - both to confirm the actual intent to pass an array and to control how it is stringified -  so it is the behavior of *advanced* functions that is the more sensible one (except for not consistently applying to *collections in general*).
Given PowerShell's commitment to backward compatibility, the behavior of non-advanced functions is unlikely to change, however.

---

<sup>[1] The only way to allow these values is to make the parameters *non*-mandatory, by removing the `Mandatory=$true` attribute property (or setting it to `$false`). Curiously, mandatory `[string]` parameters don't accept these values even when deliberately passed.</sup>

<sup>[2] Curiously, collections that aren't technically *arrays* (derived from `[System.Array]` / `[object[]]`), such as `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` or `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]`, *are* accepted and are then stringified as with non-advanced functions.</sup>

<sup>[3] Technically, you can control the separator character (string) via  [preference variable `$OFS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#ofs).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but the solution was different for me, I'll post for anyone else who may find it helpful. I was calling my function like this:

```
MyFunc param1, param2
```

But I should have passed the params like this:

```
MyFunc param1 param2
```

When you add a comma it will put the parameters into an array and pass it as a single argument, and it will pass null for the 2nd argument. This is easy to do on accident because in almost every programming language parameters are passed with a comma in between each param.