# Cannot convert value to type System.String or parameter is an empty string

Tags: powershell

I have some problem with the code of this function maybe

```
ImportContact -Mailbox $mailbox -token $token -contact $contact -FolderId $FolderId
```

I need this function to get $NewFolderId of a folder.

```
function FindContactFolders {
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]
    $Token,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]
    $Mailbox,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]
    $FolderName
)

# Construct the API endpoint to list contact folders for the specified mailbox
$apiUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$Mailbox/contactFolders"

Try {
    # Send a GET request to retrieve contact folders
    $ContactFolders = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $Token" } -ContentType 'application/json' -Uri $apiUri -Method Get

    # Return an array of objects containing the id and displayName properties of each contact folder
    $MyValue = $ContactFolders.value | Select-Object id, displayName
    if ($MyValue) {
        # Output is not empty, continue with the code
        foreach ($folder in $MyValue) {
            if ($folder.displayName -eq $FolderName) {
                # Write-Host Folder found: $folder.displayName is $folder.id
                DeleteContactFolder -Token $Token -Mailbox $mailbox -FolderId $folder.id
                $NewFolderId = CreateContactFolder -Token $Token -Mailbox $mailbox -FolderName $FolderName
                # Write-Host $NewFolderId is the ID -- $NewFolderId.GetType()
                Return $NewFolderId
            }
            else {
                if ($folder.displayName -ne $FolderName) {
                Write-Host Other Folder $folder.displayName is found with ID $folder.id
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        # Output is empty, handle the error
        Write-Host 'No contact folders found (No other folders)'
    }
}
Catch {
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
}
```

}

When I try to import that variable into another function, i receive this error:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'FolderId'. Cannot convert value to type System.String.
```

The function in which the variable is inserted is this:

```
function ImportContact {
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]
    $Token,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]
    $Mailbox,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [PSCustomObject]
    $contact,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]
    $FolderId
)

# write-host "contactcompanyname $($contact.companyname)"
# write-host $contact
$ContactObject = @"
{
    "businessPhones": [
        "$($contact.businessPhones)"
      ],
    "companyName": "$($contact.companyName)",
    "department": "$($contact.department)",
    "emailAddresses": [
        {
            "address": "$($contact.emailaddress)",
            "name": "$($contact.displayname)"
        }
    ],
    "givenName": "$($contact.givenname)",
    "surname": "$($contact.surname)"
}
"@
    write-host "contact object: $contactobject"
    $apiUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$mailbox/contactFolders/$FolderId/contacts"
    write-host $apiuri
    Try {
        $NewContact = (Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Token)" } -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $contactobject -Uri $apiUri -Method Post)
        return $NewContact
    }
    catch {
        throw "Error creating contact $($contact.emailaddress) $($ContactObject) for $mailbox $($_.Exception.Message)"
        break
    }
}
```

I have already tried changing the I parameters of the ImportContact function from

```
[parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String]
        $FolderId
```

to

```
[parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [String[]]
        $FolderId
```

But the error change to `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FolderId' because it is an empty string`

Any advice on how to solve the problem?
The variable return a string $NewFolderId and even doing Write-Host I see it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The - unfortunately obscure - error message `Cannot convert value to type System.String` implies that `$NewFolderId` contains an *array*, which in turn implies that your `CreateContactFolder` output *multiple* objects.

Make sure that `$NewFolderId` only contains a *single* value (if it isn't a string, it will be converted to one) or explicitly create a single string from the array it contains.

A simplified example:

```bash
# -> ERROR: ... Cannot convert value to type System.String.
& { 
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param([Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $String)
  $String 
} -String one, two   # !! Cannot pass *array*
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60601823/45375) for background information.

---

The other error message, `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FolderId' because it is an empty string`, after changing your parameter type to `[string[]]`, implies that `$NewFolderId` contained the *empty string* (`''`), possibly in (at least) one *element* of an *array*.

A simplified example:

```bash
# -> ERROR: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'StringArray' 
#           because it is an empty string.
& { 
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param([Parameter(Mandatory)] [string[]] $StringArray) 
  $StringArray 
} -StringArray one, '', two  # !! Cannot pass '' (empty string)
```

Note:

- It is the `Mandatory` property (whose implied value is `$true`) of the [`[Parameter()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute) attribute on the target parameter that causes empty strings and `$null` values to be rejected. *Without* this property (or with `Mandatory=$false`), the parameter accepts both empty strings and `$null` (the latter is converted to the empty string).
- However, even with mandatory parameters you can *opt-in* to allowing empty-string values with an [`[AllowEmptyString()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.AllowEmptyStringAttribute) attribute, in which case both empty strings and `$null` are accepted (again, the latter is converted to the empty string).

As an aside:

- The above applies analogously to *non*-string parameters, with [`[AllowNull()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.AllowNullAttribute) being required as an opt-in to allow `$null` to be passed to mandatory parameters.

Comment: `CreateContactFolder` has that strange behavior only within the function `FindContactFolders`; Specifically where it is now. In fact, if I try to create a folder in case `$NewFolderId` is not found, it turns out to be correct

Comment: @Alfredbel: Not knowing your `CreateContactFolder` function, I cannot speak to that. But leaving aside _why_ it behaves unexpectedly - which would be a separate question - does this answer not explain the resulting behavior?

Comment: To put it differently, @Alfredbel: This answer explains the behavior _resulting_ from what your `CreateContactFolder` function currently returns. If you're not sure _why_ your function returns what it does, _ask a new question_, ideally one with an [MCVE]. A common cause of functions unexpectedly returning _more_ than intended is PowerShell's _implicit output behavior_ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70928244/45375).